# Is it possible enable div tag do not follow the parent div padding?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I defined this css style for the child div, my parent div has been setted padding so there will have some space on the left. In the end when I insert my child div, and set the below attribute, it must follow the parents div padding.

```
width: 100%; 
margin-left: 0px; 
padding-left: 0px; 
float: left; 
clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, 0px);
left: 0px;
```

[image]

Is it possible for the child div against the parents padding?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. Do you want the child to sit outside the parent visually?

Comment: i want the child ignore the padding attribute of the parents div, i want the div width can be fit to 100% to the parents div

Comment: edit the specific div not the css <div style"padding-left:none;>Content</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the amount of padding the parent div has, you can simply reverse it like this:

```
.padding {     /* child element */
  width: 100%; 
  height:300px;
  margin-left: 50px; 
  padding-left: 50px; 
  background:#000;
}
.padding div {  /* child element */
  position:relative;  /* cling to parent */
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
  left: -25px;  /* move back to edge of parent*/
  background:#f00;
}
```

Comment: holy... this works
And can u help me over this issue? My width set to 100%, but once i reversal with 100px, my div short of length,

http://s7.postimg.org/5vcsajwl5/Untitled.png

If u can help me this will be the answer

Comment: can we do like this? width: 100% + 100px;

Comment: this is problematic because you now have a value in two places, maintenance will be trickier

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  to use "position:absolute" in the child div?

Comment: hmm, it working half, because it will straight head to the most left of the screen, which is i want is just want to fit to the left side of the parent div.
http://s2.postimg.org/ribui2t0n/Untitled.png

Comment: @RyanChong - this is the correct way to do it, see my answer for a full explanation

Answer (score 0):

if you want child div not to take padding of its parent then either dont give padding to parent div or you can set you child div with absolute position .

```css
.child {
  width:inherit;
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, 0px);
  border: solid 1px red;
  position:absolute;
  left:-1px;
}
.parent {
   border: solid 1px #cccccc;
   padding-left: 40px;
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   position:relative;
   height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">i am parent<div class="child">i am child</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, set your parent div to `position: relative;`.

Then set the child div to `position: absolute;` - this will set the child div position to a absolute value relative to the next element up the DOM hierarchy that has a position set (in this case it's immediate parent). FYI `position: relative;` sets position relative to the place the element renders. Here CSS Tricks [goes into more detail](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) at a good level for someone learning.

Once the child div is set, use the top, right, bottom and left properties to position the div as you want.

Finally, to counteract the padding, you'll need to directly set the top and left values. This will counteract the default position the child loads which takes the padding into account.

Here's an example to play with:

https://jsfiddle.net/owwcvuhp/7/

And this is the critical css:

```
.parent {
    padding: 50px;
    position: relative; /* makes child element position work */
}

.child {
    position: absolute; /* gives simple control of child position */
    top: 0; /* forces parent padding to be ignored when positioning */
    left: 0; /* as above */
}
```

Your image suggests you want the top value to be left as calculated, perhaps because content will push it down, so here's an example with `top: 0;` removed which shows the child honouring it's default rendering position, except for where the left value has over-ridden it:

https://jsfiddle.net/owwcvuhp/8/

Answer (score -1):

Please use padding-left: 0px !important; it will work.

Comment: they're targeting the child div, not the parent - plus using `!important` is the worst possible solution in css for virtually every problem